# Expand and Collapse Ajax ToolKit Accordion using Java

Tags: java, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to Expand and Collapse Ajax ToolKit Accordion using Java.

For collapsing I am using this code:

```
   function collapse() {
       $find('HeaderPane_AccordionExtender').get_Pane(0).content.style.display = "none";
   }
```

But there is a problem, I have set fade effect for accordion pane, but it will not affect while using java. How can I expand/collapse accordion with its defined properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$find('HeaderPane_AccordionExtender')._changeSelectedIndex(index, true);
```

where `index` is zero-based pane index you need to open.

Comment: Do you see this method in behavior member list?

Comment: No, How can I achieve client properties of accordion? Seems there is no documentation for it

Comment: If you use Chrome debugger you will see autocomplete list of your object fields. If you type this when browsing [Sample site](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Accordion/Accordion.aspx) `var a = $find("Content_DemoContent_MyAccordion_AccordionExtender");`, then Enter and then type `a` you will see all behavior's members.

Comment: Thank you It is working like a charm. But I did not find how to use chrome debugger. Do you mean using inspect element?

Comment: I mean when you press F12 in Chrome you will see development tools panel: http://i.imgur.com/4BKZZdT.png You can type any javascript command in Console field at bottom.